# Owner_id cannot be null. DRF relational database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am  building  relations with my tables in the database. Currently i have a tutorial lesson with 3 tables. for example (auth_user table, partyEvent table, friends table).

Now a user should be able to create just one partyEvent. Friends can join any number of partyEvent created by the users. 
The owner id in the Friends model tells the partyEvent and User 'the friend' belongs to.

I am able to restrict the users to create only one partyEvent. But when i try to register friends to a partyEvent, the owner's id is not sent. Instead the default value in:

```
owner = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', related_name = 'party', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
```

is rather sent. Why is that happening?

**models**

```
class PartyEvent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    owner = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', related_name = 'party', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')

class Friends(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',related_name = 'friends', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
```

**serializers**

```
class FriendsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.id')
    class Meta:
        model = Friends
        fields = ('id','name','owner')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have ReadOnlyField in the serializer model and that means a serialize object will have excluded a owner field when to published in DB.

Comment: i don't get the clear understanding :). I have another class with ReadOnlyField in the serializer model, yet still it submits the owner id when published in DB

Comment: So there you have a mistake. Read this https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/a8e527a4625b48914a553256f8be2907bfcc7c99/rest_framework/serializers.py#L412

Comment: How does this solve my issue :). I mean i don't understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your issue is that, ReadOnlyField in a serializer will only be included in data retrieval. When posting data through the serializer, the ReadOnlyFields are excluded.

For solving your issue, Try this,

```
class FriendsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Friends
        fields = ('id','name','owner')
```